# NSOperationQueue - executing concurrent operations without subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to have an NSOperationQueue to be able to perform following:

1. `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on NSOperationQueue
2. add dependency between the operations.
3. need ability to cancel an operation.

The problem I am facing is that the NSOperationQueue works fine only with the `Serial` operations ,since for `concurrent` operations we need to subclass the NSOperation class.

Is there any alternative to this?

FYI:
The operations which I need to schedule in NSOperationQueue have completionHandlers associated with them.

Comment: Why you think you need subclassing here?

Comment: to track whether the asynchronous operation is executing or finished

Comment: You can use dependencies for this.

Comment: dependency is used between two operations, but to tell when the first operation gets complete we need some mechanism. No ?

Comment: You can try using a s block operation with semaphores in order to wait for the callback.